# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geometry') - but hardcoding works?

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I am coding a three.js simulation/animation and am having a hard time understanding why **hardcoding** an array index to a custom class instantiation ("physicsObjects[4]") works, but using the i variable in a for loop ("physicsObjects[i]") does not.

When successful, the `updateTail()` adjusts the a three.js line position attribute, and then I must set `needsUpdate = true` as shown in the [Three.js documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/How-to-update-things) to redraw.
In the first example, it works successfully (although only for ONE of the objects, 4).

`physicsObjects[i]` has a `.tail` property which is a THREE.LineSegments(geometry,material)

```
    for (let i = 0; i < physicsObjects.length; i++) {
        physicsObjects[4].updateTail()
        physicsObjects[4].tail.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true
    }
```

It also works for 2 of my physics objects if I do this.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < physicsObjects.length; i++) {
        physicsObjects[4].updateTail()
        physicsObjects[4].tail.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true
        physicsObjects[7].updateTail()
        physicsObjects[7].tail.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true
    }
```

But if I want to iterate, it does NOT work.
The only difference is that I am indexing with 'i' instead of a hardcoded index?

```
    for (let i = 0; i < physicsObjects.length; i++) {
        physicsObjects[i].updateTail()
        physicsObjects[i].tail.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true
    }
```

This is the error I get.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geometry')
    at animate (app.js:159:32)
```

Here's my entire animate() draw loop for reference:

```
function animate() {
    //Frame Start up
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    //Force Application
    if (frameIndex % 1 == 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < physicsObjects.length; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < physicsObjects.length; j++) {
                if (i !== j) {
                    let f = physicsObjects[i].attract(physicsObjects[j])
                    physicsObjects[i].applyForce(f)
                    physicsObjects[i].updatePhysics()
                    physicsObjects[i].updateGeometry()
     
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Testing adding a tail to the objects
    for (let i = 0; i < physicsObjects.length; i++) {
        physicsObjects[4].updateTail()
        physicsObjects[4].tail.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true
    }


    const time = performance.now();
    controls.update(time, prevTime)
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    stats.update()

    //Frame Shut Down
    prevTime = time;
}
```

Why can't I iterate with a loop?

Comment: _"`physicsObjects[i]` has a `.tail` property"_... the error message proves this assumption incorrect for every value of `i`

Comment: Phil, thanks for your comment - Not disagreeing with you, but why is physicsObject[7] defined then? I'll add that even when I iterate from i=0 to i=7 in a for loop, and do physicsObjects[i],  every time it is undefined. But if I iterate from i=0 to i=7 in a for loop, and do physicsObject[7] it is defined. If it was because the .tail property is being assigned sometime later, I would still see undefined errors, so thats not it it.